# How to pass parameters to XSLT from JBoss Actions Pipeline

Tags: xslt, jboss, jboss-esb

Say I have a given action:

```
<service category="MyService" name="MyFirstService">
<actions mep="RequestResponse">
    <action class="actions.CXFListenerAction" name="CXFServiceListener"/>
    <action class="org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.transformation.xslt.XsltAction" name="Transform XML">
        <property name="templateFile" value="/stylesheets/transform_response.xslt"/>
        <property name="failOnWarning" value="true"/>
    </action>
</actions>
```

I am  trying to figure out how to add a property name or parameter that I could then access from within the XSLT. I've tried add additional property names,

```
<property name="param1" value="Hey!"/>
```

but I'm not 100% sure if this is correct for adding parameters accessible by the XSLT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties defined for the XsltAction class are properties specific to that action class and are not related to parameters in the template file.

So in short, it's not possible to pass parameters to the xslt from the JBoss ESB action pipeline. However, it would be possible to create a custom action that decorates your ESB message with data you define as a property in your jboss-esb.xml file and insert that before your XsltAction. That may be what you're looking for.